# MS SQL - Как очистить базу данных?

Tags: sql-server

Нужно удалить все таблицы.

После такого запроса остаются часть таблиц

> Сообщение 911, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 1 Database
>   'DATA-BASE-NAME' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered
>   correctly.

```
USE [DATA-BASE-NAME]
GO
 declare @i int
 set @i = 0
 while (@i<99)
 begin
 declare @table_name varchar(100)
 declare table_list cursor for
 select name from sysobjects o2 where xtype='U' and
 not exists (
 select * from sysforeignkeys k
 join syscolumns c1 on (k.fkeyid = c1.id and c1.colid=k.fkey)
 join syscolumns c2 on (k.rkeyid = c2.id and c2.colid=k.rkey)
 where c2.id = o2.id and c1.id <> o2.id
 )
 open table_list
 fetch next from table_list into @table_name
 while @@fetch_status = 0
 begin
 print 'dropping table '+@table_name
 exec ('drop table '+@table_name)
 fetch next from table_list into @table_name
 end
 close table_list
 deallocate table_list
 set @i = @i+1
 end
GO
```

Comment: А не проще было дропнуть БД и создать заново? пустую...

Comment: @Akina права пользователям мб раздавать надо. и хранимки со вьюшками никто не дропает (хотя я не силен в том, что здесь выбирается)

Comment: @teran Более чем вряд ли подобное делается из клиентского приложения (а если делается, ТС ССЗБ). Скорее всего почти одноразовое действо ленивого разработчика, которое будет изредка, но периодически, повторяться. А коли так - пусть через SSMS заскриптует нужные объекты и после пересоздания развернёт.

Answer (score 2):

В сообщении об ошибке говорится:

Проверьте правильность введенного имени базы данных. А то такой не существует :(

По всей видимости, надо заменить первую строку

```
USE [DATA-BASE-NAME]
```

на

```
USE [ВВЕДИТЕ ИМЯ БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ]
```

то есть, соответственно, заменить на используемое имя базы данных.

Comment: вроде бы очевидно, что  автор заменил имя реальной БД на `data-base-name` в коде в вопросе.

Comment: @teran, тем не менее ответ верный

Comment: @vp_arth тогда мне не понятно, как у автора удаляется часть таблиц, но не все

Comment: Я думаю, они все не удаляются :)